# when i submit data for the second time. the kode is a random number

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $data = "SELECT max(nomor) as nomor from tbl_permohonan";
    $sql = mysql_query($data);
    if($sql === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
  }
  $i= mysql_fetch_array($sql);
// ID OTOMATIS//***************************************************
  $kodeawal=substr($i['nomor'],2,7)+1;
  if($kodeawal<10){
    $kode='190281000'.$kodeawal;
  }elseif($kodeawal > 9 && $kodeawal <=99){
    $kode='19028100'.$kodeawal;
  }else{
    $kode='1902810'.$kodeawal;
  }
  ?>
```

[image]
[image]

I think I wrong on `$kodeawal=substr($i['nomor'],2,7)+1;`, but I dont know where is the bug. So help me fix it. Thanks !

Comment: I think you're leaving out some relevant code. What you're showing above will always produce the same result as long as no values are added to or changed within `tbl_permohonan`.  Also, this code doesn't actually _do_ anything aside from assign some values to variables.  Nothing is output or returned from a function or anything like that.  Please provide additional context, sample inputs, and desired outputs.

Comment: Additionally, you should not be using the `myslq_*` library.  You should be using either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

The whole code looks like a strange way to prepend index-values with a given number.

The part `if($kodeawal<10){…}elseif($kodeawal > 9 && $kodeawal <=99){…}` is obviously used to prepend some zeros so that the resulting number is always the same length. In PHP there is [a function to do so: `str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
echo str_pad(1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
// yields: 001
```

And for the line `$kodeawal=substr($i['nomor'],2,7)+1;` I assume, that the content of the field `nomor` is of the same format as the `$kode`. In that case, try to avoid such string operation and add the one directly, probably after converting the SQL string result in to an integer:

```
$kodeawal = 1 + (int)$i['nomor'];
$kode = '1902810' . str_pad($kodeawal, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```